# Syntax errors with my php code

Tags: php, curl

I m struggling with a piece of code. I already know that there are
    errors with this code. It uses cURL. The curl process works
    perfectly however i have added an if statement to check a logic in
    order to pass certain variables to the other server. Thanks in advance..

```
<?php
    include("../config.php");

    if ( !isset( $_COOKIE['admin'] ) ) {

    include_once("login.php");
    echo ("<div id='quote'>Error: Can not access page.");
    }
    else {
    if (isset($_GET['user']) && ($_GET['user'] != "") && isset($_GET['licence']) && ($_GET['licence'] != "") &&
    isset($_GET['to']) && ($_GET['to'] != "") && ($_GET['username'] !=
    "")) {
    $username = $_GET["username"]; 
    $idlisc= $_GET["user"];
    $licence = $_GET["licence"];
    $to = $_GET["to"];

    $acc = new Account;
    $acc->changeVis($idlisc, $licence, $to);
    header("Location: search.php?user=".$username); 

    if ($get["lic_".$i.] == 11 || 12 || 13 || 14 || 15 || 16 || 17 || 18 || 19 || 20) {

    $ch = curl_init(); //http post to another server

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://xxx/add-user");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "codes=$licence");

        // receive server response ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    print_r($server_output);

    curl_close ($ch);
    }
    else {
    $ch = curl_init(); //http post to another server

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://xxx/add-user");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "usr=$username&code=$licence&password=$id");

        // receive server response ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    print_r($server_output);

    curl_close ($ch);


    }


    }
```

Comment: And what's the syntax error?

Comment: I just want to know what are the syntax errors of my code or it limitations etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two syntactical errors

```
if ($_get["lic_".$i.]
     -------------^ // Remove this dot
```

Secondy, you need to close a brace at the very end of your code

```
curl_close ($ch);
  }
 }
} //<---- Add a brace here
```

**EDIT :**

Check if your **`if`** statement like this

```
if ($_get["lic_".$i] == 11 || 12 || 13 || 14 || 15 || 16 || 17 || 18 || 19 || 20)
```

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply. Should I worry that it still showing this error in dreamweaver or should I ignore it anyway

Comment: First of all don't use dreamweaver. Get a good editor like PHPStorm or NetBeans IDE. Well what is the error it shows ?

Comment: when i run on the browser I get this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' in /changevis.php on line 29